# Procedure executed, but not displaying results

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a procedure and executing it. It is getting executed as well. but not displaying the result. I am missing some basic steps that's why this is happening. Please help.

```
 set serverout on;
    Create or replace procedure pro1 (a number) is 
    x varchar2(30);
    begin
    select last_name into x from employees where employee_id= a;
    end;
    /

    declare
    y varchar2(30);
    begin
    pro1 (102);
    dbms_output.put_line (y);
    end;
    /
```

Comment: Didn;t you get any error when you ran the anonymous block to call the procedure?

Comment: what front end client are you using to execute it...`toad`, `sql-dev` ...?

Comment: NO. I dint got any error while executing the procedure in an anonymous block. It got executed properly. But no output is showing. Iam using isql* plus in oracle 10g database

Comment: One more, if you testing your code better to variable add some string..
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('value x = '||x); and you will always know if dbms working, otherway if x is null, you wont see output.

Answer (score 1):

Do as the following in order to see the output

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pro1 (i_param IN VARCHAR2, o_param OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   SELECT LAST_NAME
     INTO o_param
     FROM employees
    WHERE employee_id= i_param;
END;
```

and execute procedure as

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE       
   z   VARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
   pro1 ('535', z);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (z);
END;
/
```

If your procedure doesn't have any DML statements, it is better to use a function.

Comment: Right even when I tried using an out parameter the procedure works. Or I put DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE while creating the procedure then also it will work.
But without using DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE in procedure creation and later executing is not returning any result. but it should do. But I am not yet clear why it is not returning results

Comment: @user2788235 I didn't quite understand what exactly you mean by not returning any results? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Well If you see my main post, there I have declared a "local variable" to fetch the result of the procedure (in your example you have used an out parameter to do the same). at the same time I have used "dbms_output.put_line" in the executable part and not in the procedure creation part. You also have done the same.
Now I am saying procedure is getting executed in both the cases but in my case it is not displaying result though it is getting executed.

Now if I use "dbms_output.put_line" in the procedure creation part, then it is displaying result.

Comment: @user2788235 I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do with `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line`. If would want to return value from procedure, then you need to have `OUT` parameter.

Comment: even without having out parameter procedure can return value.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to display the last_name of the employee with id 102. To be able to get the lastname from pro1 you should create function instead of procedure, as procedures can not return any value. Try this:

```
 set serveroutput on;
    Create or replace function pro1 (a number) return varchar2
    is
    x varchar2(30);
    begin
    select last_name into x from employees where employee_id= a;
    return x;
    exception when no_data_found then
    return 'no employee with this id';
    end;
    /

    declare
    y varchar2(30);
    begin
    y:=pro1 (535);
    dbms_output.put_line (y);
    end;
    /
```

Comment: PUT in [SERVEROUTPUT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12040.htm#SQPUG099) is optional.

Comment: When I run 'set serverout on', I get the following: "SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set serverout on", but when I run 'set serveroutput on' it works ok.

Comment: Using "set serverout on" instead of "set serverout on" giving same results.

Comment: Do you want to display last_name for the employee with employee_id 102?

Answer (score 0):

Even without having "OUT Parameter" procedure can return result.
Find below the example:

```
set serverout on;
Create or replace procedure pro1 (a number) is 
x varchar2(30);
begin
select last_name into x from employees where employee_id= a;
dbms_output.put_line (x);
end;
/

declare
y varchar2(30);
begin
pro1 (102);
end;
/
```